# Side effects of calling Assembly.Load multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, load, assemblies

If one calls `Assembly.Load` multiple times does it cause any side effects?

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
   Assembly.Load(assemblyStrongName);
   // .......
}
```

This loads the assembly one time doesn't it? I've checked with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` before and after and it seems it's loaded one time (as it should) but does it have side effects?

In a long running server application (runs for months/years with no restart) does the above cause any issues?

Comment: If you have a system that, the loading of assemblies is the critical part of it staying active for months/years, I'm impressed.

Comment: Corollary - if you're chasing a memory leak, use appropriate tools to identify the actual objects being leaked, rather than looking at your source code and randomly guessing at would "could" be the leak.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm not chasing memory leaks. I've never manually loaded an assembly 'till now so It was just (programmer) curiosity :).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> This loads the assembly one time doesn't it?

Yes.  The assembly gets loaded into the current AppDomain, and will only be loaded once into that AppDomain.  Calling this multiple times just returns the existing assembly.

Comment: @JohnDoDo No - it should just return the existing Assembly.  It's impossible to load an assembly >1 time in an AppDomain, and once loaded, it'll never unload (until the AppDomain is shut down)

Comment: If Assembly.Load(byte[] rawbytes) is used (bytes instead of a filename as a parameter), then the assembly will be added to the collection (AppDomain.GetAssemblies()) on every call.